# Left Join Preserving NULL Records

Tags: sql, t-sql, left-join

Say I have these tables:

```
TableA        TableB:
id name       id  name
-- ----       --  ----
1  Pirate     1   Rutabaga
2  Monkey     2   Pirate
3  Ninja      3   Darth Vader
4  Spaghetti  4   Ninja
```

When I `Left Join` I get the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name

id  name       id    name
--  ----       --    ----
1   Pirate     2     Pirate
2   Monkey     null  null
3   Ninja      4     Ninja
4   Spaghetti  null  null
```

But what I want is a different **"**`Left Join`**"** where I get the following:

```
id  name       id    name
--  ----       --    ----
1   Pirate     2     Pirate
1   Pirate     null  null
2   Monkey     null  null
3   Ninja      4     Ninja
3   Ninja      null  null
4   Spaghetti  null  null
```

How would I get this augmented **"**`Left Join`**"** that returns null records for all left table entries along with the joined values?

Comment: Where would IDs of 5 and 6 come from?

Comment: You have no records in your `TableA` with id=2, name=Pirate, so by what logic should that appear in your results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT TableA.id, TableA.name, TableB.id, TableB.name 
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.name = TableB.name
UNION
SELECT id, name, null, null 
FROM TableA
```

Note that you don't need a `LEFT JOIN` in there because the second query obviates the need for doing that.  You are asking for the `INNER JOIN` results plus records with `TableA`'s data with just nulls for `TableB`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `union all`.  Of course, there is an issue with the ids.  Something like this might work:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as id, name, bid, bname
from ((select a.id, a.name, b.id as bid, b.name as bname
       from tableA a inner join
            tableB b
            on a.name = b.name
      ) union all
      (select a.id, a.name, NULL, NULL
       from tableA a
      )
     ) ab;
```

This doesn't preserve the first `id` column.  But then again, it is hard to say what that is for.

EDIT:

Actually, this might preserve it the way you want it:

```
select id, name, bid, bname
from ((select a.id, a.name, b.id as bid, b.name as bname
       from tableA a inner join
            tableB b
            on a.name = b.name
      ) union all
      (select a.id + (max(id) over ()), a.name, NULL, NULL
       from tableA a
      )
     ) ab;
```